# How do i prepare my ambient for a Android Studio Native project?

Tags: android, config

I have a problem and I would like your help :)

I received a native Java project from Android Studio and I want to know how I can configure my environment, the first time I tried I had a lot of errors with gradel.

Is there a way to know exactly what settings are needed to start project maintenance?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have installed Android Studio and are able to create sample projects, you should be set up.

Gradle should show you all the problems which your legacy project has. I assume, that you will see a lot of warnings which can be ignored at first.

You might have problems with a missing `key.properties` file.
Some dependencies might not be available anymore.

You have to resolve all the issues manually. There aren't any special settings.